# nop with argument in x86_64

Tags: x86

A program I'm investigating has the following code (disassembled by IDA with some light censorship by me):

```
__text:....B9                 call    <redacted>
__text:....BE                 nop
__text:....BF                 nop     dword ptr [rax+00h]
```

I have two questions. First, why would the compiler have inserted these `nop`s? They don't appear to be for any alignment purpose.

Second, what is that `nop` with a relative addressing argument? Its hex is `0F 1F 40 00`. Looking at http://ref.x86asm.net/, this does appear to be an instruction called "hintable NOP", but I'm having trouble finding relevant information about it.

By the way, the next instruction starts at `....C3` and is a real/productive instruction (that is, not a `nop` or anything morally equivalent to a `nop`).

Answer (score 11):

These are multi byte `nop` instructions. 

From http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/NOP.html

> **Description**
>
> This instruction performs no operation. It is a one-byte or multi-byte
>   NOP that takes up space in the instruction stream but does not impact
>   machine context, except for the EIP register.
>
> The multi-byte form of NOP is available on processors with model
>   encoding:
>
> The multi-byte NOP instruction does not alter the content of a
>   register and will not issue a memory operation. The instruction’s
>   operation is the same in non-64-bit modes and 64-bit mode.
>
> **Operation**
>
> The one-byte NOP instruction is an alias mnemonic for the XCHG (E)AX,
>   (E)AX instruction.
>
> The multi-byte NOP instruction performs no operation on supported
>   processors and generates undefined opcode exception on processors that
>   do not support the multi-byte NOP instruction.
>
> The memory operand form of the instruction allows software to create a
>   byte sequence of “no operation” as one instruction. For situations
>   where multiple-byte NOPs are needed, the recommended operations
>   (32-bit mode and 64-bit mode) are:
>
> ```
> +---------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
> | LENGTH  |           ASSEMBLY             |         BYTE SEQUENCE        |
> +---------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
> |         |                                |                              |
> | 2 bytes |  66 NOP                        |  66 90H                      |
> |         |                                |                              |
> | 3 bytes |  NOP DWORD ptr [EAX]           |  0F 1F 00H                   |
> |         |                                |                              |
> | 4 bytes |  NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + 00H]     |  0F 1F 40 00H                |
> |         |                                |                              |
> | 5 bytes |  NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 +  |  0F 1F 44 00 00H             |
> |         | 00H]                           |                              |
> |         |                                |                              |
> | 6 bytes |  66 NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 |  66 0F 1F 44 00 00H          |
> |         |  + 00H]                        |                              |
> |         |                                |                              |
> | 7 bytes |  NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + 00000000 |  0F 1F 80 00 00 00 00H       |
> |         | H]                             |                              |
> |         |                                |                              |
> | 8 bytes |  NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 +  |  0F 1F 84 00 00 00 00 00H    |
> |         | 00000000H]                     |                              |
> |         |                                |                              |
> | 9 bytes |  66 NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 |  66 0F 1F 84 00 00 00 00 00H |
> |         |  + 00000000H]                  |                              |
> +---------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
> ```

Comment: Nitpick: this same table appears in Intel's official reference (and unless my memory deceives me, the description is very similar). Perhaps it's better to point OP to that instead.

Comment: @Jongware: the linked site is generated from Intel docs

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your first question, `NOP`s are issued by the compiler when it's interested in aligning the code following it, usually because that code is target of a jump (such as in a loop) and it's beneficial for it to be aligned to a paragraph (16-byte boundary) or a cache line (32-byte boundary).

In other words, it does so to increase performance.