# What kind of assembly language construct is this?

Tags: disassembly, assembly

I am reversing an ELF64 executable created on AMD X86-64. I encountered this line near the end of the file and am puzzled to its meaning:

```
nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

In this case `rax` contains `0x2329`.  However, `nop` means '*do nothing*', so I am puzzled as to why there are arguments included on the line.  The code is loaded with `libc` function calls so I am assuming the source code is C/C++ and not GAS.

[This post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11971/nop-with-argument-in-x86-64) has good content but perror's explanation is more apropos and contains more "why" than a mere recital of the Intel docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nop with argument in x86\_64](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11971/nop-with-argument-in-x86-64)

Comment: Thank you.  I missed that posting somehow.    It is similar however I believe the response "The one-byte NOP instruction is an alias mnemonic for the XCHG (E)AX, (E)AX instruction" is not valid on IA-32 and 64 processors.  At least according to the Intel documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mainly two usage of the `nop` instructions:

1. They are quite often used as padding at the end of assembly procedures or in-between procedures. And, in this case one may want to pad with "*more than one byte at the time*", this is why they added extra arguments (that are just ignored most of the time).

   See: [NOP instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) (Wikipedia) and [NOP—No Operation](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/NOP.html) (x86 Instruction Set Reference).
2. They can also be used to delay a bit the ALU in between two memory fetches in order to give the pipeline a chance to get a correct prediction of the data values. And, this is probably your case because this instruction perform a small arithmetic computation when computing `rax+rax*1+0x0`, therefore the ALU has is really delayed because of this operation.

   See: [Delay Slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot) (Wikipedia).

Comment: Thank you.  Looking at the surrounding code the delay slot answer makes complete sense.  It very much resembles the   `NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX *1 +  0x0`   8 byte eample in the Intel docs.